# Cleanest way of aborting if request if parameters missing

Tags: json, flask, parameters

I'm checking if all JSON parameters needed for my method are present in the request, and aborting if it's missing some:

```
@app.route('/test/tags', methods=['POST'])
def update_tags():
    data = request.get_json()

    if not all(key in data for key in ('_id', 'port', 'tags')):
        abort(400)
```

This works all right, it just seems like such a common thing that would need done that I was wondering if Flask had a built-in way of dealing with this?

Comment: Don't know about a built-in, but a simple decorator could make the code shorter and more readable, e.g. `@require_json('_id port tags'.split())`

Comment: You can use some packages to validate your parameters. For example [flask-inputs](https://github.com/nathancahill/flask-inputs) or [flask_request_validator](https://github.com/d-ganchar/flask_request_validator) or [flask-restplus](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html)